# find out duplicate entry while editing the person name information in angular

Tags: angularjs

I can create people information with their b'date using add button. It get displayed top of the page. If i want to edit information, I again click on that information and edit it easily. I need one validation there that i should not choose bday.name(person name) duplicate. e.q. if i already have "peter" person so i can't edit and change any other person name to "peter". so need to avoid duplicate entry in list.

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/2UFfaG?p=preview

```
$scope.newBirthday = function(){

    $scope.bdays.push({name:$scope.bdayname, date:$scope.bdaydate});

    $scope.bdayname = '';
    $scope.bdaydate = '';

};
```

Comment: iterate `$scope.bdays` before save or in a change handler

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple solution using only angular js :

```
  $scope.newBirthday = function(){
      var exist=false;
      angular.forEach($scope.bdays, function(bday) {
           if(bday.name===$scope.bdayname){
             exist=true;
             bday.date=angular.copy($scope.bdaydate);
           }
      });
      if(!exist){
               $scope.bdays.push({name:$scope.bdayname, date:$scope.bdaydate}); 
      }
        $scope.bdayname = '';
        $scope.bdaydate = '';

    };
```

Comment: You did avoid duplicates while creating new person. i need while user edit it on run time on clicking on it.